# Alternate methods to adjust brush size/strength for sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, customization, 3d-mouse

I'm using Blender, and I'm trying to use my Ipad tablet with Astropad to do digital sculpting. I'm running into an issue trying to adjust the size/strength of a brush without having to move my left hand from the keyboard, or my right hand from the tablet.

[image: Radial Control]

Normally, you would press F, drag the mouse left/right to adjust the size/strength of the brush, then left-click/press Enter to confirm the change. However, with my tablet, as soon as I put my pen to the screen, it automatically "clicks" and doesn't give me the chance to adjust before confirming. This forces me to either use a mouse to adjust the size, or take my left hand off the keyboard and touch the screen to simulate a hover, which isn't convenient.

Ideally, I would like to disable confirm on click, so that I can drag the pen on the screen to adjust the size/strength without relying on "hovering". I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that though. I found the radial control settings for adjusting the settings of a brush, and I see a "confirm on release" option, but that only makes it so that it confirms when I release F, it does not disable confirm on click. Is there a setting or action to disable confirm on clicks in radial menus?

Alternatively, is there a way to adjust the size/strength of a brush using an ndof controller such as a 3d mouse, as opposed to a regular mouse? I have a 3dconnexion space mouse, and if possible, I would love to adjust the settings using the knob on the 3d mouse instead.

Thanks.

[image: Radial Control Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The brush settings** such a radius, strength, pressure, and a few other things, **can be changed by the context menu**. Just right-click to open it. (I hope this helps with the pen issues):

[image: context menu]

If you can't right-click with the pen or you have chosen the "right-click to select" option, then the default key to open the context menu is <kbd>W</kbd>. **But in Sculpt mode there is a keymap conflict** (Blender 2.93), because the new *Face Set Edit* pie menu also has <kbd>W</kbd> key assigned, and wins. To be able to open the context menu you need to change one of the key bindings.

If you use "left-click to select" (default for Blender 2.8+) you don't need to change anything.

**Keymap/Key bindings** can be found here (or search for key-binding: W):

- main menu *File > Preferences*, section *Keymap*, then *3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global)* - (It's a huge list)
- [image: settings in preferences]